# "Autocorrelation problems can be addressed by using the Hansen method to adjust R2"?

Tags: regression, self-study, autocorrelation, r-squared

The question I am trying to solve does not give the autocorrelation statistics, but does provide the regression coefficients and t statistics associated with them.

I know autocorrelation can be adjusted by the Hansen method, but is this directly related to adjusting $R^2$?

I don't believe we need the actual autocorrelation statistics to answer this question. My answer choices ask if the quote in title is

- correct
- incorrect
- the regression does not provide enough information